# Bundle not filling

Tags: java, android, bundle, android-bundle

I'm trying to send some data from an activity to its fragment. I've bundled the data, but when I try to retrieve it in the fragment it comes up empty.

Graph.java (fragment)

```
private void setData() {

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(new Entry(0, (float) 4.8));

        Log.e("set", "method reached");

        LineDataSet set1;
        if (mChart.getData() != null &&
                mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            set1 = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(values);
            mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Blood Glucose Levels");
            set1.setDrawIcons(false);
            set1.setLineWidth(4f);
            set1.setCircleRadius(5f);
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
            set1.setFormLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setFormSize(15.f);
            set1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);

        }
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set1);
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();

******
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            Log.e("if", "if reached");
            float myDataSet = Float.parseFloat(getArguments().getString("INPUT"));
            Log.e("data", "data retrieved");
            float count = 0;
            float mcount = count + 1;
            values.add(new Entry(1, 4));
            values.add(new Entry(mcount, myDataSet));
        }
******

        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("resume", "onResume reached");
        setData();
    }
}
```

Tabbed.java(base java class of the fragment)

```
//getting inputs from room and putting them into the view in table
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mInputViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InputViewModel.class);
        //only add if there is a new input
        Log.e("result1","onActivityResult tabbed reacher");
        if (requestCode == INPUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //retrieve input from room database
            Input1 input1 = new Input1(data.getStringExtra(input.EXTRA_REPLY));
            //insert the inputs into the view model of the recyclerView
            mInputViewModel.insert(input1);

            //convert the String input1 to a double
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(input1.getValue());

*****
            //send d value to graph.java
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Log.e("Testing", "Bundle made");
            bundle.putString("INPUT", String.valueOf(d));
            Graph myObj = new Graph();
            myObj.setArguments(bundle);
*****
            }

            //display pop-up if no input is added don't save the input
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.empty_not_saved,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I've marked the bundle and retrieving code with ****. From my logtrace, I know that the bundle code is running and the setdata() method is running, but the 'if' statement never does. I've added the code `if (getArguments() != null) {` to avoid a java.lang.nullPointerException.

I think that the data is being bundled correctly, but for some reason it's coming up as null in the fragment. I may have coded some of it wrong - this is my first try using bundles.

EDIT: I have a livedata and View model class set up, but I'm unsure how to implement them to update the data.

InputViewModel.java

```
    private InputRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Input1>> mAllInput1s;
    public InputViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new InputRepository(application);
        mAllInput1s = mRepository.getAllInput1s();
    }
    LiveData<List<Input1>> getAllInput1s() {return mAllInput1s;}
    void insert(Input1 input1) {mRepository.insert(input1);}
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `Graph` instance you create there. That instance does indeed have its arguments set, but unless you transact that instance, it's not really going to be used. If you're trying to update something in a "live" `Fragment`, you can't do it with arguments, which is a one-shot kinda deal that you can only set before the `Fragment` is transacted.

Comment: thanks for the help @MikeM. What would you suggest doing instead?

Comment: Well, the newest fad is a `ViewModel`/`LiveData` setup, but the cheap and easy route is to just put a `public` method in the `Fragment` to update and refresh your graph. You have to be careful with that, though, 'cause `Fragment`s might not behave as you expect; e.g., during recreation upon a device rotation, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @MikeM. - you're a lifesaver. I've updated my question to include the ViewModel class I already had set up for saving the inputs (sorry, I wasn't aware it was relevant otherwise I would have included it originally). Can you show me/direct me to some resources on how to create that setup to update my graph with the inputs. Otherwise, could you explain more/direct me to some resources on how to do it through the public method (i'm not worried about device rotation). Again, thank you so much!!!

Comment: If you're going with the `ViewModel`/`LiveData`, then there's no need for the `public` method. It's relatively simple, when you get your mind around it. [The overview page for `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) has a pretty straightforward example. Your setup would be somewhat like [the sharing between `Fragment`s example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing), except the `MasterFragment` there would be your `Activity`.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. I've added the Viewmodel to my fragment, but I'm unsure on how to extract the data from the list and set it as the chart data